# Form absolute uri from a relative path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible in a controller to form an absolute uri from the relative path 
to another controller action?

In rails application, specifically from a controller,
I am trying to redirect to outside link with a back redirection link set in params, 
so that outside application could redirect back to my application at that address.

From 'mypath/1' in development environment the function would return

```
http://localhost/mypath/1
```

In deployed environment it would return

```
http://mysite.com/mypath/1
```

**Update:**
for my purpose **url_for** fits well:

```
url_for :controller => 'tasks', :action => 'testing', :host => 'somehost.org', :number => 
'33'  # => 'http://somehost.org/tasks/testing?number=33'
```

So, the question's resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking is:

```
url_for :controller => 'tasks', :action => 'testing', :host => 'somehost.org', :number => '33'  # => 'http://somehost.org/tasks/testing?number=33'
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the routes that you have in config/routes.rb, you can have the path and complete url.
E.g. users_path vs. users_url

Answer (score 0):

rails 3 method is **request.fullpath**. Url for any route can be derived by using **url** instead of **path**. 
if route is **user_path** then url is **user_url**